# Amazon Fire (TV) In-app Purchase: Subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-fire-tv

I am currently working on a test app for Amazon's In-App Purchasing SDK for Android. Specifically, I am working on Fire TV, but the problems also seems to appear on a Fire Tablet.

I created a (currently unpublished) App on my Developer account and added a subscription with both an annual and a monthly option.

Here is the exported JSON:

```
{
    "inapppurchasingtestabo.monthly": {
        "price": 1.07,
        "subscriptionParent": "inapppurchasingtestabo",
        "smallIconUrl": "http://",
        "title": "Subscription",
        "itemType": "SUBSCRIPTION",
        "description": "This is the subscription!",
        "languageTitleMap": {
            "DE": "Abo",
            "US": "Subscription"
        },
        "languageDescriptionMap": {
            "DE": "Das ist das Abo!",
            "US": "This is the subscription!"
        },
        "currencyPriceMap": {
            "US": 0.0
        }
    },
    "inapppurchasingtestabo.annually": {
        "price": 10.72,
        "subscriptionParent": "inapppurchasingtestabo",
        "smallIconUrl": "http://",
        "title": "Subscription",
        "itemType": "SUBSCRIPTION",
        "description": "This is the subscription!",
        "languageTitleMap": {
            "DE": "Abo",
            "US": "Subscription"
        },
        "languageDescriptionMap": {
            "DE": "Das ist das Abo!",
            "US": "This is the subscription!"
        },
        "currencyPriceMap": {
            "US": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

I installed the Amazon App Tester App on the device and copied the JSON to `/mnt/sdcard/amazon.sdktester.json`.

While everything seems to work in principle - from the app I can see the subscription along with the available prices, the descriptions, etc. and I can also make a purchase which then shows up in the App Tester App - **I see no indication as to which price is for which subscription period**.

Compare the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**Can you tell which price is for the monthly and which is for the annual subscription?** (Also, keep in mind, that for all the user knows, they could be bi-weekly and semi-annual, too).

So my question is: **What am I doing wrong and how do I get the purchase dialog to display the period along with the price?**

Comment: How were you able to get the App Tester app installed on the Fire TV? Trying to work through Fire TV IAP also, and the tester app doesn't appear to be in the app store on the device, and I don't see a direct download for sideloading it in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: Interesting - I can't find it through the device interface anymore, either. But you can just log into Amazon with the account you are using on your device and go to: http://www.amazon.de/Amazon-App-Tester/dp/B00BN3YZM2/ and push it to the device from there.

Comment: thank you @david.mihola! I was hopeful, but it looks like the App Tester has not been updated with the latest Fire TV update, it shows as incompatible with my registered Fire TV on that page. I'll poke Amazon about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug or limitation with the Amazon App Tester app. From my experience, it does not fully replicate the production environment. It's useful for testing the basic workflow locally.

I would recommend you to use [Live App Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing) which allows you to test in the production environment.

Comment: You'd think that would bear mentioning in the documentation... Anyway, thank you for making the first sensible contribution to my search for an answer - something neither the Amazon Dev Forums nor Dev Support could provide. I am a bit intimidated by the Tax Information Interview - do you know if I have to complete it to be able to do Live App Testing of In-App purchases?

Comment: You should be able to test IAP with Live App Testing by setting the IAP item price to free or $0. I don't think it let you set a non-zero price if you haven't completed the tax form.

Comment: Holy cow! "Does not fully replicate" is kind of an understatement - when I do Live App Testing not only does the purchase dialog show the period along with the price, it's a completely different dialog! Totally different layout! Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Amazon app tester has not been updated with the new offerings they have developed in the in app purchases. I would advice to conduct a beta test to ensure that app works. App tester is a mock app that pretends to fulfill purchases. Beta test (Live app test) would test your app against the actual amazon services that executes in app purchases in real world (production for published app).